# Webpacker "Hello World from Webpacker" not displaying in console, cannot move forward

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to switch from Sprockets to Webpacker and mostly using this guide:

https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79

There are a few other guides but the initial steps are the same.

I followed everything closely and have found no errors, but "Hello World from Webpacker" is not showing up in the console, suggesting that it is not linking the js file properly. I installed yarn as a prerequisite, installed webpacker with no issues, and then added this to app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Restarted server several times, no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT 1: Here are all the scripts running when I inspect the source, as one commenter requested:

```
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-2b8935521e2301b06b45bd42e623eb0c0acf76c3a6ba383b7429c6a2884f8c23.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/activestorage.self-1ed4604ac2170045f1ffca4edb81a75246661555e4f9cf682bb8a21825e32e1c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery3.self-e200ee796ef24add7054280d843a80de75392557bb4248241e870fac0914c0c1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/popper.self-70e1b2b78096eb80eb35ebac513e7a8007033ee3e881919cfdca4ece7779cffd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-91405a85c7ea7ffc2407472f08a86cd29ba078b4e18f962931a4cf3270a7ba4d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/lib/abstract-chosen.self-ff43f2db4e91fea824844eb4d37566bc7248e435c3ea7050d7a252c1c14e4d9a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/lib/select-parser.self-16f32cef24f1cae19e8b5f5dab3ac72e6fb35ce24fe5ae41d354d60f9bb53491.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/chosen.jquery.self-c1b0ad79c75d520f72310f2594a76189b7c6e407c035a9a4c9022dff262b49a5.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/chosen-jquery.self-6a3cf5192354f71615ac51034b3e97c20eda99643fcaf5bbe6d41ad59bd12167.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/google_places.self-dff88f7305718f246a9ed130e8ec03a82098539df2a08ff9774a610bc84d42ca.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/merge_requests.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-6a7f81c89608537f1c0b5e6e1a1cad14caec515ae09b88e0406efa9bcbfd4752.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb I have the following tags:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I know that the latter two javascript tags might be conflicting somehow, but it doesn't make a difference if I take the old tag out completely.

SOLVED: It was a really stupid error of course. The homepage of my site was the only page that didn't use the application layout. It had its own. There was no issue, as soon as I tried any other page it was fine. Ugh.

Comment: Can you show all the `<script>` tags from your page in `<head>`? You can get this by right click on webpage --> View Page Source

Comment: Also, the Webpacker or sprockets JS won't fire up if your webpage is `Hello Rails` page which is generated when you create a new app. The `application.html.erb` will run only if you have valid controller and view.

Comment: I have added all of this information to my original post as it was long. I would appreciate a look, thank you! The whole app is quite far along, so it's not a Hello Rails page.

Comment: The problem is `javascript_pack_tag` is not working/rendering. Did you add `gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'` gem to your `Gemfile`? Then did you run `rails webpacker:install`? Is your `application.js` file is present in `assets/javascript/packs` folder?

Comment: I just replicated a new app with Rails 5.2(default to sprockets), then created a scaffold --> Added webpacker gem to `Gemfile` --> Run `rails webpacker:install` (Yarn must be installed) --> then add `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` in `application.html.erb` --> I can see the `Hello World from Webpacker` in console

Comment: Yep, I did all of that, exactly. Ugh.

Comment: Can you create a file `app/javascript/packs/index.js` --> add `console.log` --> in `application.html.erb` add `javascript_pack_tag 'index'` and see if that's working?

Comment: Hi Allen: It turned out to be something really dumb - of course. See my edit. But thank you for your help and generosity!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the same thing. Keep `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

run `rails g controller pages index`

go to `localhost:3000/pages`

and that's where I found my console.log

confirm in config/routes you have:
`resources :pages`